# Passing a value into a method that is triggered by an event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a simple todo app using React.

An unordered list (`<ul>` is used to present all the items in my list. Within that are list items (`<li>`), and with a list item is a button with an `onClick` handle attached to a class method:

```
<button onClick={this.onHandleClick.bind(this)}>Add</button>
```

In the method, I need to prevent the default behaviour to prevent the page refreshing when the button is clicked:

```
onHandleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```

My question is, what can I do if I want to pass a value into `onHandleClick`, given that `event` is given as the argument?

Comment: `onClick={event => this.method(event, arg1, arg2)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wrap your event handler in another function** and pass item specific parameters this way:

```
<button onClick={e => this.handleClick(e, itemId)}>Add</button>
```

---

```
handleClick(event, itemId) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(itemId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with React, but if the value is static, you could do something like this:

```
<button onClick={function(){self.onHandleClick(passedInValue);}}>Add</button>
```

Note that "self" would need to be bound to whatever object contains the 'onHandleClick' method.

Comment: be aware in your example `this` will not be the surrounding class and will not contain the event handler